# Full-disk encryption prevents booting from USB

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb, encryption

I have the following problem:
I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64Bit on my Lenovo Yoga 500 14ISK. I apparently chose the full encryption option which now seems to interfere with booting another OS form an USB stick. I so far have tried:

1. Changing the boot ranking in BIOS
2. Using the hotkey method (F12) and choosing the USB stick

Everything leads to the ubuntu screen where I am asked to type in the "sad3_crypt" password.

The partitions on my laptop which are displayed after the command
    `fdisk -l`
are the following:

```
Medium /dev/loop0: 162,6 MiB, 170479616 Bytes, 332968 Sektoren
Einheiten: sectors von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorengröße (logisch/physisch): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
I/O Größe (minimal/optimal): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes


Medium /dev/loop1: 81,6 MiB, 85549056 Bytes, 167088 Sektoren
Einheiten: sectors von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorengröße (logisch/physisch): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
I/O Größe (minimal/optimal): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes


Medium /dev/sda: 119,2 GiB, 128035676160 Bytes, 250069680 Sektoren
Einheiten: sectors von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorengröße (logisch/physisch): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
I/O Größe (minimal/optimal): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
Typ der Medienbezeichnung: gpt
Medienkennung: 98E11C7C-12AC-4B83-AF4D-6392BB3DB268

Gerät        Start      Ende  Sektoren Größe Typ
/dev/sda1     2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda2  1050624   2050047    999424   488M Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  2050048 250068991 248018944 118,3G Linux filesystem


Medium /dev/sdb: 28,7 GiB, 30752000000 Bytes, 60062500 Sektoren
Einheiten: sectors von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorengröße (logisch/physisch): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
I/O Größe (minimal/optimal): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
Typ der Medienbezeichnung: dos
Medienkennung: 0x55032ee1

Gerät      Boot Start     Ende Sektoren Größe Id Typ
/dev/sdb1        8192 60062499 60054308 28,7G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)


Medium /dev/mapper/sda3_crypt: 118,3 GiB, 126983602176 Bytes, 248014848 Sektoren
Einheiten: sectors von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorengröße (logisch/physisch): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
I/O Größe (minimal/optimal): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes


Medium /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: 114,5 GiB, 122901495808 Bytes, 240041984 Sektoren
Einheiten: sectors von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorengröße (logisch/physisch): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
I/O Größe (minimal/optimal): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes


Medium /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: 3,8 GiB, 4081057792 Bytes, 7970816 Sektoren
Einheiten: sectors von 1 * 512 = 512 Bytes
Sektorengröße (logisch/physisch): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
I/O Größe (minimal/optimal): 512 Bytes / 512 Bytes
```

(sorry, my OS is set to german language)

Is there some other way I can bypass the full encryption to be able to boot from my USB stick?

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: i had this issue and had to boot from a legacy BIOS rather than UEFI

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the USB stick isn't bootable, which is why the machine isn't booting from it and reverting to booting from the hard disk. Linux FDE is software-only and does not interfere with the BIOS boot order.

However, have you recently tried booting the machine with Ubuntu 17.10 (*not* 17.10.1)? If so, the machine would now appear to be affected by [this issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1734147).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In fact I have already tried another USB stick before that (forgot to put that in the original post) Maybe both of them are not bootable then ?

Comment: @FelixS. You're very welcome! Welcome to AskUbuntu. If someone's answer was helpful to you, please upvote it. If their answer actually answered your question, please accept it. If both, then please do both!